# Access context within anonymous function

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

i want to access processAfterDone in the following code, but i get a Reference error, because i'm in an anonymous function. I use Base.js for class inheritance. If you know something better than that i'm open for this. I tried self.processAfterDone() and this.processAfterDone(). I can't figure out if this problem is caused by me, jQuery or the way Base.js works. Any help appriciated. Now the code:

```
var Test = Base.extends({ // uses Base.js for class like javascript - see http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/

    callAjax: function() {
            requestAccessToken().done(function() { // does an ajax call and passes the ajax return object to access .done()
                    console.log("call processAfterDone");
                    processAfterDone();
            });
    },

    processAfterDone: function() {
            console.log("processAfterDone");
            //do more stuff here
    }
```

})

Comment: i could rather use .done(processAfterDone); but i have to pass the context to this again, to use the class fields in processAfterDone. any ideas on that thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by using `.done($.proxy(this, 'processAfterDone'));` took me 2 days to figure that out. hope this helps out a lot of people.